# Can somebody help me out with this expression written in assembly using arithmetic operations?

Tags: assembly, x86

The expression: `EAX = 7*EAX - 2*EBX - EBX/8`
My code:

```
start:
    mov EAX,9
    mov EDX ,7
    mul EDX ; EAX<-EAX*EDX
    mov EDX,EAX ; EDX<-EAX*EDX<=>(7*9)
    mov EBX,8
    mov EAX,2
    mul EBX; EAX<- EAX*EBX (2*8)
    mov ECX,EAX
    sub EDX,ECX; <=>7*EAX-2*EBX (7*9-2*8)
    mov EAX,EBX
    div EBX ; EAX <=> 8/8
    sub EDX,EAX; <=> 7*9-2*8-8/8
    push 0
    call exit
end start
```

Comment: mul changes both eax and edx. div ebx divides edx:eax by ebx and changes both eax and edx. The simplest way to fix this is to use a different register in place of edx, and be sure to clear edx before div. (There are better ways. You don't need mul or div at all.)

Comment: To multiply by 7, shift left by three and subtract the original number. To divide by 8 shift right by three.

Comment: @prl: IMO, the simplest way is `imul eax, ebx`.  Or `imul eax,7`.  In 32-bit code, there's basically no reason to use one-operand `mul` except when you specifically *want* the high half result in EDX.  As you say there are better ways, e.g. with LEA, but those are as simple if not more simple.

Comment: @Peter, that doesn't help with div, which is why I suggested using a different register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> EAX = 7*EAX - 2*EBX - EBX/8
> ```

It is not because an expression contains multiplication (*) or division (/), that your solution should be using these operations.

- For `7*EAX` you can use the simpler `imul eax, 7`.
- Instead of doubling `EBX`, you could simply subtract `EBX` twice.
- And for calculating an eighth of `EBX`, you should simply shift its value 3 times to the right.

```
imul eax, 7
sub  eax, ebx
sub  eax, ebx
shr  ebx, 3
sub  eax, ebx
```

Comment: Thanks but I had to solve it with only arithmetic operations. Finally I figured it out even though it is not as efficent as yours

Here is my new code if you re interested
```

start:
 ;EAX = 7*EAX - 2*EBX - EBX/8
 mov EAX, 14
 mov EBX, 15
 
 mov EDX, 7
 mul EDX ; EAX <- 7 * EAX
 
 mov ECX, EAX ; creating a copy of eax
 mov EAX, EBX ;
 
 mov EDX, 2
 mul EDX ; 2*EBX
 sub ECX, EAX ; ECX <- 7* EAX - 2*EBX (salvat in ecx)
 
 
 mov EAX, EBX
 mov EBX, 8
 div EBX; EBX / 8
 sub ECX, EAX ; ECX <- 7EAX - 2EBX - EBX/8
 
 mov EAX, ECX
 push 0
 call exit
end start

Comment: @AttilaOrban: `imul` is an arithmetic operation; no reason to still use clunky one-operand `mul` that writes the high-half result to EDX unless you specifically want that. And here you don't because you're truncating to a 32-bit result to fit in EAX. Also, right shift is unsigned arithmetic division by a power of 2; `sar ebx, 3` is "arithmetic" right shift, i.e. signed division (with rounding towards -Inf instead of truncation towards 0 like idiv).  But there's more of an argument to be made there that it's not doing "arithmetic".